# Correct gradient for canvas

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas, html5-canvas, konvajs

I want to display svg file as path in konva.

But I have a problem with styling.

And radialGradient doesn't apply well.

And I also don't want to use Konva.Image.

I write both here:

VSG file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg id="Game" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="540.1" height="540.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 540.1 540.1">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="linear-gradient" x1="40" y1="0" x2="40" y2="80" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#fff"/>
      <stop offset=".2" stop-color="#fbfbfb"/>
      <stop offset=".3" stop-color="#f2f2f2"/>
      <stop offset=".5" stop-color="#e1e1e1"/>
      <stop offset=".6" stop-color="#cacaca"/>
      <stop offset=".7" stop-color="#acacac"/>
      <stop offset=".8" stop-color="#888"/>
      <stop offset=".9" stop-color="#5d5d5d"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#333"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <circle id="Player" cx="40" cy="40" r="40" fill="url(#linear-gradient)"/>
</svg>
```

JS:

```
var circle = new Konva.Circle({
    radius: 40,
    fillLinearGradientStartPoint: { x: 40, y: 0 },
    fillLinearGradientEndPoint: { x: 40, y: 80 },
    fillLinearGradientColorStops: [0, '#fff', 0.2, '#fbfbfb', 0.3, '#f2f2f2', 0.5, '#e1e1e1', 0.6, '#cacaca', 0.7, '#acacac', 0.8, '#888', 0.9, '#5d5d5d', 1, '#333',],
    //gradientUnits:"userSpaceOnUse"
    scale: { x: 3, y: 3 }
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fillLinearGradientStartPoint` and `fillLinearGradientEndPoint` are relative to origin of the shape. In case of `Konva.Circle` it is center of the circle.

Do this:

```
const shape = new Konva.Circle({
  x: 200,
  y: 200,
    radius: 40,
    fillLinearGradientStartPoint: { x: 0, y: -40 },
    fillLinearGradientEndPoint: { x: 0, y: 40 },
    fillLinearGradientColorStops: [0, '#fff', 0.2, '#fbfbfb', 0.3, '#f2f2f2', 0.5, '#e1e1e1', 0.6, '#cacaca', 0.7, '#acacac', 0.8, '#888', 0.9, '#5d5d5d', 1, '#333',],
    scale: { x: 3, y: 3 }
});
```

Demo: https://jsbin.com/qibanicuto/1/edit?html,js,output